# Update Yolo V8 training with another dataset

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8, roboflow, ultralytics

I trained a YOLO V8 model using a dataset downloaded from [here](https://universe.roboflow.com), and I used Ultralytics and Roboflow library.
I used the following command (using the pre-trained model `yolov8n.pt` downloadable [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v8.1.0/yolov8n.pt)):

```
yolo task=detect mode=train model=C:\Training\yolov8n.pt data=C:\DATASET\DIRECTORY\data.yaml epochs=20 imgsz=640
```

this command created a file named `best.pt` in:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\runs\detect\train\weights
```

which I was able to use for detecting objects. However I'm not completely satisfied with the results, so I'd like to update the training (keeping the previous training) with another dataset. Is there a specific command for doing so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way here is to start the training on a new dataset from your `best.pt` checkpoint:

```
yolo task=detect mode=train model=C:\Users\USERNAME\runs\detect\train\weights\best.pt data=C:\DATASET\DIRECTORY\data.yaml epochs=20 imgsz=640
```

There are some nuances.

- You can't actually add up train results from different trainings to each other. In this case, you only start the training from the already good point, but they can be rewritten during the current training, especially if the new dataset has a different class list or the images in it are severely different from the first dataset. So-called ["catastrophic forgetting"](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/5908#issuecomment-1776281564).
- Consider lowering the learning rate for the second training process to save more information from the first training. Also, you may want to freeze the first n layers of the trained model and train the remaining part of it. The available training arguments are here: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/train/#arguments.

In case you need the model to equally consider the information from the different datasets, it is better to unite them into one and train the model on this united data.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. If I want to freeze the first n levels as you suggest, is there a way I can use to understand how many levels should I freeze?

Comment: Yes, look at the model [cfg](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/cfg/models/v8/yolov8.yaml). The common way to start is to assign freeze=10 which is equal to the first 10 layers - the model's entire backbone. Try and decide, if you need to lower this value or use a list of separate values, or change the entire approach. Freezing also reduces the training time.